# How do I correctly index a nested set in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, tree, nested

I'm working with this structure:

```
id | name | parent_id | lft | rght
```

It looks like as of right now there's an index on all of these columns, manually added. Index_type is BTREE and Collation is A for each column.

I'm working with another person's table on this, and am trying to find a way to speed it up. It's my first experience with databases, but from other materials found on StackOverflow some recommend adding an index on multiple columns together ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428978/nested-set-indices-performance) for example).

Other posts reference unique indexes versus spatial indexes and other concepts behind indexing this type of structure. What would you say would be required for an optimized nested set such as this so run the fastest? I want to work with these indexes and can scrap the previous ones if they were added in error or are not the correct type of indexes.

Comment: Show us the SELECT; without it, we cannot recommend an INDEX.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql for a cookbook on such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query optimizer will only select one index.  Having a multiple column index (aka. composite index) can be useful.  However, that depends on what kind of queries you will be running on your table.

If you have a composite index it will still work on the first column in the tree. SO, say you have a composite index on A, B, C.  If you are running a query that only needs column A it will still work.  However, it loads that entire index of A, B, C into the cache. You can run into memory issues, especially if your index is on large varchar fields.

You can read more about composite indexes [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).